# Sharepoint Workflow Manager installation failure: "None of the declared nodes is for the current machine."

Tags: sharepoint-2013, workflow-manager-1.x

When installing and configuring Workflow Manager 1.0 for Sharepoint 2013 Foundation, I got this error when kicking off the execution via the GUI (which really just runs a bunch of PowerShell scripts):

> Windows Fabric configuration started.   Running Windows Fabric
>   deployment.   Program C:\Program Files\Windows
>   Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code.1.0\FabricDeployer.exe exited with
>   error: Windows Fabric deployment failed. DeploymentValidator: warning:
>   The Fabric Data Collection Agent is disabled for this deployment. None
>   of the declared nodes is for the current machine.

Many sites recommend removing all references to localhost/127.0.0.1 from your HOSTS file, but my HOSTS file is empty. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was that the cluster manifest file generated by Windows Fabric was cloned from another VM, and the nodes in it were not correct.

1. Delete all of the **ClusterManifest.*.xml** files in *C:\Program Files\Windows Fabric\bin*,
2. Restart the **Windows Fabric Host Service**.
3. Verify your ClusterManifest.*.xml files have a Node entry under Infrastructure.WindowsServer.NodeList with an IP Address or fully-qualified-domain-name for your server.
4. Re-run the configuration wizard.